# Up/down keys don't work with angular material design in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on a project with angularJS.

There is a owl carousel gallery, When you click on an image from the gallery, Material Angularjs dialog box opens with all of these large images...
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

I want to scroll these images inside dilogbox, they scroll fine with mouse wheel but not with the Up/Down arrow keys.

These keys are work on a regular web page on focus of the div.

Answer (score 1):

You should open a bug request with angular material so that they can fix it for you. If I open the custom dialog of Angular material then the up/down keys doesn't work by default.

Or insert a nested div inside a fixed div and add ng-keypress and move it manually.